# Ruby way to group anagrams in string array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, anagram

I implemented a function to group anagrams.
In a nutshell:

input: ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', scream']

output: [["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["four"], ["for"], ["potatoes"],["creams", "scream"]]

I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.
I really think I used too much repetition statements: `until`, `select`,
`delete_if`.
Is there any way to combine the `select` and `delete_if` statement? That
means, can selected items be automatically deleted?

Code:

```
def group_anagrams(words)
  array = []
  until words.empty? 
    word = words.first
    array.push( words.select { |match| word.downcase.chars.sort.join.eql?(match.downcase.chars.sort.join ) } )
    words.delete_if { |match| word.downcase.chars.sort.join.eql?(match.downcase.chars.sort.join ) }
  end
  array
end
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Anagram Using String#sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517745/ruby-anagram-using-stringsum)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like that:

```
 a = ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', 'scream']
 a.group_by { |element| element.downcase.chars.sort }.values
```

Output is:

```
[["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["for"], ["potatoes"], ["four"], ["creams", "scream"]]
```

If you want to you can turn this one-liner to a method of course.

Comment: Rule #1 of Ruby programming: learn the methods of `Enumerable`. Rule #2: see Rule #1. :-)

Comment: Its weird that this works on my machine, but not in heroku! My site goes down when I have this on heroku...

Comment: When I run this, I only get:

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `partition` function instead of select, implemented in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition). It splits the entries within the array according to the decision-function into two arrays.

```
def group_anagrams(words)
  array = []
  until words.empty? 
    word = words.first
    delta, words = words.partition { |match| word.downcase.chars.sort.join.eql?(match.downcase.chars.sort.join ) } )
    array += delta
  end
  array
end
```

(untested)