# How to sort array of words into arrays of anagrams in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, hash, anagram

http://spark-university.s3.amazonaws.com/berkeley-saas/homework/hw1.pdf

Trying to part 3 of this assignment. The following code does not seem to work, namely for the parameter `['HeLLo', 'hello']`, returning `[["hello"], ["HeLLo"]]` instead of `[["HeLLo", "hello"]]`

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
    #iterate through words, make hashmap with the sorted version
    hash = {}
    words.each do |x|
        hash[x.chars.sort.join.downcase.gsub /\W/, ""] = []
    end

    #iterate through words, access hashmap and append curr to array
    words.each do |x|
        hash[x.chars.sort.join.downcase.gsub /\W/, ""] << x
    end

    hash.values #return array of values
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. (I'm new to Ruby)

Comment: give us the input string, and expected output.

Comment: this was asked just some days ago, search a bit. Also, if you want to group, maybe the method `group_by` is what you should be looking at.

Comment: try this `hash.values.flatten(1).reverse.each_cons(2) {|x| p [x]}`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646995/ruby-way-to-do-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do it like this:

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
  anagrams={}
      words.each do |word|
        anagrams[word.downcase.split('').sort.join] ||=[]
        anagrams[word.downcase.split('').sort.join] << word 
      end
      anagrams.values
end
```

Comment: check the duplicated question to see a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646995/ruby-way-to-do-this

Comment: +1, was just looking for the group_by option to correct my self :)
i am gonna leave this here, i don't wanna copy other peoples code although i did want to do something with `group_by`. Everyone looking for a better option check @toklands link. thnx @tokland